# how to get regex form from csv in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to enter all details regarding a test plan from csv file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/890jF.png

[${regex} is the variable that contains the regular expression which should be filled there instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/890jF.png)

i have the regex as variable, but it is not treating it as one, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

If it doesn't - either your regular expression is not correct or your `${regex}` variable is not set.

1. Test your regular expression using "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. Double check `{regex}` variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor)

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information regarding JMeter tests troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri there was a problem with my csv which had a different file endings, did it on ms office, just worked. The problem was with libre office.